# Using Adobe Test-and-Target, how do I avoid seeing the first page before the redirect kicks in?

Tags: ab-testing, test-and-target

I've got an A/B Test set up in Adobe Test-and-Target.  The idea is that 50% of the time, visitors to a certain page should be redirected to a different page instead.  It is working correctly, in that half of users are sent to the new page.

However, sometimes the entire original page is loaded before the redirect happens.  I put the mbox in the head tag of the page, which I thought would ensure the redirect happened before any HTML was displayed to the user, but that's not happening.

How can I create a seamless result for the user, where the redirected users only see the new page loading, and never see the original page?

Comment: Where in the page is the mbox being defined and how are you using redirecting? with window.location?

Answer (score 0):

For our site, the `<script src="http://maur.imageg.net/js/mbox.js" ></script>`is at the very end of the head tag and works fine.

Comment: Looking a bit deeper, I found this in an HTML Offer:

Comment: `<style id="flickersuppression">
#wrap {visibility:hidden !important}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){var c=function(s,f){if($(s)[0]){try{f.apply($(s)[0])}catch(e){setTimeout(function(){c(s,f)},1)}}else{setTimeout(function(){c(s,f)},1)}};if($.isReady){setTimeout("c=function(){}",100)}$.fn.elementOnLoad=function(f){c(this.selector,f)}})(jQuery);
jQuery('#wrap').elementOnLoad(function(){

$("#wrap > div:eq(0)").replaceWith("");

jQuery('#flickersuppression').remove();

})

</script>`

Comment: OK, I'm trying to parse this - it is adding a style to the entire page that doesn't allow it to display until everything is loaded, then it removes the CSS that is hiding the page.  Is that right?

Comment: Correct. (Full disclosure- I did not write this code. Also, in case you didn't notice, I edited out all of the files in the .replaceWith(""); function.) This is the only part of one of our past A/B tests that focuses on the flicker issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your mbox.js should be as close to the top as possible and then your inline mbox should be defined preferably right after the  tag.  This way the request is made before the content starts to render, and the redirect kicks in before the guest even sees the page.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using anything post DOM related for example jQuery's:

document.ready( function{});

If you paste your code you're using for the A/B - we be able to review & respond accordingly.

However pure Javascript and pure CSS should execute seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS first to not show anything

```
<style>
  body {display:none!important}
</style>
```

Then use JavaScript to redirect the page to new page.